# Regular expression - Find ocurrences that has one string

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Im trying to find all files modified during de last 24 hours in /var/www/vhost directory.

That is working ok with the find command, then, I want to filter the list because i don't want  jpg files, jpeg files and so on.

Now i have this and it's working ok:

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -ctime 0 -type f | grep  -ve ".jpg$" | grep -ve ".jpeg"
```

I guess (and know) there's a better solution to my problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your find command itself to

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -not \( -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.jpg" \) -ctime 0 -type f
```

Comment: This is working, thanks!: 
find /var/www/vhosts/ -ctime 0 -type f -not -name "*.jpg" -not -name "*.jpeg" -not -name "*.gif" -not -name "*.pdf" | grep -v "/statistics/"

Comment: You need to accept the answer if the solution is working fine in case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-regex` and `!` (negation):

```
find $DIR -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.*\.(gif|jpg|pdf|png)$'
```

Comment: What if i want all files except jpg, png, gif, pdf? any kind of "or" in the regex?

Comment: @Chux: the negation takes care of the "all except" part. You can get an OR with `\.(jpg|pdf|png)`, but you must then set the regex type with `-regextype`. I'll cook up an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with one find command:

```
find /var/www/vhosts -ctime 0 -type f \! -iname \*.jpg \! -iname \*.jpeg
```